# Formatting a string in php

Tags: php

Can anyone help with this formatting. I have a paragraph in a database with says (for example) 'black;blue;green' and I want to call it from the db and the format all the ; to be new lines \n.

so it becomes

```
black 
blue 
green
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

```
$string = str_replace(';', "\n", $string);
```

Comment: Ty -  the problem is it now outputs black\nblue\ngreen instead of putting them on a new line

Comment: Make sure you have double quotes around the `\n`, not single quotes

Comment: I do but still no joy - it doesnt show '\n' but it doesnt put them on a new line either

Comment: Perhaps you need a HTML line break `<br>` as well?

Answer (score 0):

`$str = str_replace(";", "\n", $string);`

Finds the `;` and replaces it by newline.

[Refer this for more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)